kubectl explain Subsequent entries cannot be automatically completed
kubectl explain   Subsequent entries cannot be automatically completed.
System: Centos 7 2009
Executed commands
yum install bash-completion -y  
echo "source <(kubectl completion bash)" >> /root/.bashrc
logout

After execution, some commands can be automatically completed, but   kubectl explain not OK
for example
[root@master ~]# kubectl s
scale  (Set a new size for a deployment, replica set, or replication controller)  set    (Set specific features on objects)
[root@master ~]# kubectl s

I'm not sure if it's due to something missing.
The "kubectl explain" section can be automatically completed. But it won't work in the future.
for example
[root@master ~]# kubectl explain  
myapp_expose.yaml                     
[root@master ~]# kubectl explain

I have pressed the "TAB" button multiple times, but the displayed content is a file in a certain directory, not a resource type.

Can you elaborate on what you are expecting when you mentioned kubectl explain is not auto-completing. Cause as mentioned if you use kubectl e it will give suggestions to auto-complete like kubectl edit, kubectl events, kubectl exec, kubectl expose.

Hello Dharani Dhar Golladasari
I'm sorry for not making it clear
The "kubectl explain" section can be automatically completed. But it won't work in the future.
for example
[root@master ~]# kubectl explain
myapp_expose.yaml
[root@master ~]# kubectl explain
I have pressed the "TAB" button multiple times, but the displayed content is a file in a certain directory, not a resource type.
Thank you for Dharani Dhar Golladasari's reply.

AFAIK kubectl explain command won’t auto-complete the resource which you are trying to get the explanation for. If you try using the tab key after typing the kubectl explain by default as same as any other command it will give you the files available in the path as a suggestion but not resources explanation. To use the kubectl explain command, you need to enter the resource type which you want the explanation. If you want to know the list of kubernetes services available in your cluster use the following command
$ kubectl api-resources

From the output of the above command select the resource which you want to know the explanation example as follows :
    $ kubectl explain [Resource-type]

EX: $ kubectl explain deployment

    $ kubectl explain deployment.spec

To know more detailed information refer to this official kubernetes kubectl explain document. You can refer to this tutorial by Vivek singh to get more information.
Note: You need to connect to a cluster before using the kubectl explain.

Is there any solution that can automatically list these resources?
For example, writing code.
Because I saw that the automatic completion of Kubectl is also written by scripts.

Do you mean you want the automation script to list the api-resources?

yes
I hope to write kubectl explain and press the tab key a few times to list resource objects and subsequent content
thanks!
